# Заменить слэш на нижнее подчеркивание(Регулярное выражение)

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Здравствуйте! Подскажите, пожалуйста, как в строке заменить прямую косую черту на нижнее подчеркивание '_'.
Ниже код, но почему-то не работает:

```
$vv = 'SAMSUNG/1';
$model = str_replace('\/', '_', $vv);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваш код не работает, потому что для регулярных выражений используется функция [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.preg-replace.php). В случае с [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.str-replace.php), правильный код будет выглядеть вот так:

```
$vv = 'SAMSUNG/1';
$model = str_replace('/', '_', $vv);
```

Если стоит условие использовать именно регулярные выражения, то:

```
$vv = 'SAMSUNG/1';
$model = preg_replace('/\//', '_', $vv);
```